# Easy to use interface to program a custom call center

Tags: voip, asterisk

I aim to implement a customer service call center without any experience on the similar projects.

Working principles:

```
- Incoming call:
  * Determine if the caller is a customer or or employee based on caller ID
    * If employee, allow him to use a number operated menu to check him/herself in or out
    * If customer, determine question category by using a number operated menu. Place 
      him/her on queue.
        -> Search for available employees and call them automatically.
        -> Once the employee picks up, connect him/her to the customer. Start a timer 
           for billing the call. Start recording the call.
        -> On hang-up, stop the timer.
        -> (Optional) If an employee hung up and customer is still on the line, ask for
           a number operated grade on how well he/she was served. From number press till
           hang-up, save an audio recording for oral feedback.
        -> Save customer's number, employee ID, timestamps, recording of the call and 
           optional feedback and the number operated menu entries to a database.

The core functionality consists of menus and matchmaking. Call recording and feedback can
be implemented later or left out.
```

I have looked into Asterisk and it looks promising. Are there additional modules to Asterisk I should look into before starting more in-depth designing? Are there other tools than Asterisk to consider? Are there any points to take in consideration that might save some trial-and-error? What literature would would you recommend? Is this project too heavy and doomed to fail for an intermediate programmer to start with?

I would greatly appreciate your input on previous topics and general guidance overall.

Comment: I'd be very careful to use callerID as authentication to internal menus. Its rather easy to fake and many networks don't properly validate incomming callerID as they should.

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth taking a look at [Twillio](http://www.twilio.com).  I've used the SMS integration with a C# application and it was really easy to use.  I haven't used Asterisk, so I can't compare.

Comment: This service seems awesome and I would definately use it if I found a way around the fact that I am from Finland and "We currently do not offer other access to Twilio beyond traditional PSTN phone numbers". No love for Finland :(

Comment: oh... that's a bummer.  I hope to see Twillio expand soon.  They have a really nice service.

Comment: Yeah. It's baffling that they have a highly polished communications service with no VoIP support O_o

Comment: Try tropo.com, it's more comprehensive than twilio and also covers more areas.

Answer (score 0):

Try either Voxeo [Prophecy](http://evolution.voxeo.com/) or [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/home.jsp) Services.  They have locations in Europe and the US. For more advanced call center applications I would use Prophecy because it supports open standards like [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/) and [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/).  As the name implies CCXML gives you fine grain control on handling inbound and outbound calls, conferencing, and other features you mention in your requirements. You can develop and test applications for free on their network and only pay when you put it into production. Voxeo's support is excellent and they provide it for free, even if you are just developing your application.

You can also purchase an on-premise solution for Prophecy if you do not want to run it as a service in the cloud.  It is the exact same software that is running in the cloud and since the development language is based on standards any apps developed for their cloud service will run on their premise-based solution. They will give you a 2 port solution for free for testing and the per-port cost for additional ports is very reasonable.  The telephony interface for Prophecy is SIP, so if you need to hook up to TDM type lines (ex: T1 or analog) you will need to purchase a VoIP gateway.  Voxeo resells a decent one or you can go with a CISCO gateway.

Answer (score 0):

There's Aculab Cloud ( http://cloud.aculab.com ) too - this provides C#, Python and Web APIs for common telephony functionality, with a comprehensive call routing and management system.

Disclaimer: Software Developer for Aculab.